# SAML steps to implement

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

i have java web project `SampleServlet1.war` which contains login servlet based on mysql credentials i gets login and i copied that project and created as another web project `SampleServlet2.war`... how i need to implement the `SAML SSO` between this two web projects.

Please help to find out the steps to follow to implement SAML SSO. what are things to do implement SAML SSO

Answer (score 0):

In your case system one validates a user, creates and encrypts a SAML token and the client then uses this when talking system two (Usually inside the Authorization header as a bearer token.) System two has the public key of System One and can decrypt the token. System Two trusts System One so if the decryption is successful, the assertions inside the token are good.

What you find usually is that you have an Identity Provider where people log in and get their SAML token. You then have service providers (your apps) that then trust that the IdP did it's job.